# How do I find the cardinality of strings in this set?

Tags: induction

Given a string $w \in \{1,2\}^*$, let $F(w) \in \mathbb{N}$ be the sum of all the numbers in it. For example, $F(\epsilon) = 0$ for the null string $\epsilon$, and $F(1212) = 6$. Now define some $$S_n = \{ w \in \{1,2\}^*: F(w) = n\}$$

Some examples: $\epsilon \in S_0$ and $1212 \in S_6$.

I want to find the cardinality of $S_n$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and prove this is correct.

My thoughts:

1. Seems like this is a question fit for induction, but I have some trouble finding the induction hypothesis, which is essentially the task of "finding the cardinality of $S_n$.
2. From another perspective, it seems that I can possibly using something like the CBS theorem to show the cardinality if I can find $S_n$ as bijective to some $[n]$ and then relate it to say $\#S_n = n$

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  a string with sum $n$ can either start with a string with sum $n-1$ to which a $1$ is added or a string with sum $n-2$ to which a $2$ is added.  Compute a few terms.  You should recognize the sequence.

Comment: Thank you I have seem to found the recurrence relation for it, namely $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2}$ and used this as my inductive hypothesis.